# Construct a bar chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I wanted to construct a bar chart using chart.js. I typed this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bar chart</title>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
    <script>
        var my = new Chart(chr).Bar(data);
        var chr = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var data = {
            dataset: [
                {
                    label: "my first dataset",
                    fillColor: "blue",
                    strokeColor: "green",
                    data: [65, 53, 80, 83, 55, 45]
                }
            ]
        };
        var myfirstChart = new Chart(chr).Bar(data);
    </script>
    console.log(ctx);
</body>

</html>
```

...and it says there is cannot "read property length undefined".

What is the error and how to correct it?

Comment: Hi @Aishwarya, I tried to salvage the code by formatting it. I left original issues like `console.log(ctx)`  outside of the `<script>` (I understand that is not your main problem). Please clarify what your problem is, include the full error message, and the stack trace. And then maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: the first line of your script uses two variables defined later. Comment or remove the line var my = new Chart(chr).Bar(data);

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Bar chart</title>
 <script src="Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>

 <script>
 //var my= new Chart(chr).Bar(data);
  var chr= document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  var data= {
    dataset: [
        {
         label: "my first dataset",
         fillColor: "blue",
         strokeColor: "green",
         data: [65, 53, 80, 83, 55, 45]
        }

    ]};
    var myfirstChart= new Chart(chr).Bar(data);
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
  Html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Js:

```
 var chr = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: ["One", "Two"],
        datasets: [{
          label: "my first dataset",
          backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C"],
          fillColor: "blue",
          strokeColor: "green",
          data: [65, 53]
        }]
      }
    };
    var myfirstChart = new Chart(ctx, data);
```

Comment: no,it is not working this way either.  i typed 2 files html fils having only canvas and js file having the Js code...it says $ is not defined.:/

Comment: @aishwarya add jQuery reference to fix $ not defined issue

Answer (score 0):

Joseph i have made some correction in script as following. its working fine try this.

```js
<script>
      var chr = document.getElementById("canvas");      
      var ctx = chr.getContext("2d");     
     ctx.canvas.width = 800;
     var data = {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: ["One", "Two"],
        datasets: [{
          label: "my first dataset",
          backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C"],
          fillColor: "blue",
          strokeColor: "green",
          data: [65, 53]
        }]
      }
    };
            
        
    var myfirstChart = new Chart(chr , data);
    </script>
```